# How to add more than one array to kendo chart

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui

I have more than one array, I want to add them to Kendo chart, I did the search could not get the solution, it will be helpful if you help me.
[see the example here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/data-binding#bind-scatter-series)

Suppose I want to add one more array like this

```
[{
        x: 33, y: 50,
    }, {
        x: 15, y: 26
    } ]
```

to the `xyData` object, How can I do? I have applied directly like

```
var xyData = [[{
        x: 10, y: 20,
    }, {
        x: 100, y: 200
    } ], [{
        x: 33, y: 50,
    }, {
        x: 15, y: 26
    } ]];
```

this but it did not work, How to do? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Array.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)** to create one new array:

```
var xyData = [{
        x: 10, y: 20,
    }, {
        x: 100, y: 200
    } ];

var xyData2 = [{
        x: 33, y: 50,
    }, {
        x: 15, y: 26
    } ];

var xyTotal  = xyData.concat(xyData2);
```

## **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/roBMmG)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. it works fine but it combines into single series, `xyData2` data should be the second series values and could you change `type: "scatterLine"` in the code please? because I need scatterLine chart.

Comment: @thippu, in that case just set the data for each series: https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/WLbxBP

Comment: @ezankar , Can we able to set the series data dynamically? like using loops?

Comment: @thippu, you can use setOptions to change series dynamically: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/methods/setoptions